# Is a pointer to a stack object deleted when out of scope?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having a hard time trying to understand exactly what I'm supposed to do with my pointer members in my classes. I know that any pointer created with new[] must be deleted with delete[]

But, what if my pointer points to the address of an object created on the stack? Do I have to delete it? Or will it be deleted when the class is destroyed. And if so, in what way am I supposed to delete it? The clarify the issue, here's some of my code.

**Moves header file: Moves.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "ShuffleBag.h"

class Character;

class Moves
{
private:
    Character* pm_User;
    ShuffleBag m_HitChances;

public:
    Moves (Character& user);
    ~Moves ();
};
```

We can see that I have a pointer member to a character object.

**Moves Source File: Moves.cpp**

```
#include "Moves.h"
#include "Character.h"



Moves::Moves (Character& user)
{
    m_HitChances = ShuffleBag ();
    m_HitChances.Add (true, 8);
    m_HitChances.Add (false, 2);

    pm_User = &user;
}

Moves::~Moves ()
{
}
```

And here we can see that I assign this pointer to the address of the passed in reference of the character object.

**Character Header File: Character.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "Moves.h"
#include "ShuffleBag.h"

class Character
{
public:
    int m_Health;
    int m_Energy;
    Moves* pm_Moves;

public:
    Character ();
    Character (int health, int energy);
    ~Character ();

};
```

Likewise, here I have a pointer to a move set for this character. This is because the moves do not have a default constructor.

**Character Source File: Character.cpp**

```
#include "Character.h"



Character::Character ()
{
    m_Health = 100;
    m_Energy = 50;

    pm_Moves = &Moves (*this);
}

Character::Character (int health, int energy)
{
    m_Health = health;
    m_Energy = energy;

    pm_Moves = &Moves (*this);
}

Character::~Character ()
{
}
```

And here I assign this pointer the address of the newly created Moves object. So my question in a TL;DR format is this:

Are my pointers pointing to stack objects and when the classes die, will the pointers themselves? Or will I have to delete them?

Comment: First, classes never die. Instances (= objects) sometimes do.  Second, you have to decide if an instance Character is the *owner* of the Moves object. If so, if should explicitely delete it in the destructor (called when the Character is deallocated). Third, you'd better user smart pointers.

Comment: Only an object created by operator `new` needs to be `delete`d.   One thing to watch is a pointer that points at an object that passes out of scope - that pointer cannot be dereferenced, since it points at an object that no longer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *only* need to call `delete` on a pointer that is returned by `new`. There is no exception to this rule.

In your case though,

```
pm_Moves = &Moves(*this);
```

is assigning a pointer to an *anonymous temporary* `Moves(*this);`. It's that pointer that's immediately invalided after the statement! The program behaviour on using that pointer for anything is *undefined*.

So you obviously need to redesign all this. Consider looking at `std::unique_ptr` when you refactor.

Comment: I see, I see. Your answer combined with the other comments makes sense. I'm definitely going to be re-designing this, and was planning to make use of smart pointers. The only reason pointers came into this is because I was trying to make the character a reference member in the Moves class. But when I tried to pass a character reference with _*this_ it complained about a deleted function. A lot more understanding is needed about these it seems, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that any pointer created with new[] must be deleted with
>   delete[]

I've seen this confusion over and over again. **You don't delete pointers**, **you delete objects**. Or better to understand, if you talk about `malloc` / `free`: you don't free pointers, you free memory. The pointer just points to the object(s) / memory you need to delete.

E.g.:

```
int a = 24;          // just an int

int* p1 = new int;   // new allocates memory for an int,
                     // creates an int at that location
                     // and then returns a pointer to this newly created int
                     // p1 now points to the newly created int

int* p2 = p1;        // p2 now also points to the created int
p1 = a;              // p1 now points to a

// what do we delete now? p1?
// no, we don't delete pointers,
// we delete objects dynamically created by new
// what pointer points to those objects?
// at this line it is p2
// so correct is:

delete p2;
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no new dynamic element created in this class, so you cannot destroy it.

Comment: Please read [the good answer guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and provide more detail with your answer.